# Audio Recording from a microphone to a wav file using Qt

Tags: qt, audio, microphone, recording

I am trying to do an application with the purpose of being able to record phrases and have them automatically saved in a chosen directory as wav files. For this I am trying to use the QAudioRecorder class. When I hit the record button I speak something into the microphone and .wav file gets saved into the directory that I chose with the name that I want, but when I playback the file it is just noise. I don’t think I am using the recording class properly.

What I have so far is :

```
void RecordingWidget::startRecording()
{
    if(audioRecorder->state() == QMediaRecorder::StoppedState)
    {

        //Set Audio Input
        audioRecorder->setAudioInput(audioRecorder->defaultAudioInput());

        // Sets Output location where to store the file
        if(!m_outputLocationSet)
            setOutputLocation();

        // Set recording Settings
        QAudioEncoderSettings settings;
        settings.setCodec("audio/amr");     // Not sure what to put here
        settings.setSampleRate(16000);
        settings.setBitRate(32);
        settings.setQuality(QMultimedia::HighQuality);
        settings.setEncodingMode(QMultimedia::ConstantQualityEncoding);

        audioRecorder->setEncodingSettings(settings);
        audioRecorder->record();
    }

    else {
        stopRecording();
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me out, any guidance greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I did a sample implementation usind the code from the man page, without the QAudioEncoderSettings stuff. It worked instabtly...